# Weird behavior when scrolling with DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, grouping

I am working with WPF DataGrid and using multilevel grouping over that. I am using expander in template and having indentation to represent multilevel. Functionality wise it is working good but when I group it and further scroll it Horizontally, it shows weird behavior.

1. Group section scrolls with data row
2. Data gets clipped from left

Any help please!!!